# WordPress Theme activation hook?

Tags: themes, init

I know the many tricks to see if said theme is activated, I have scoured the internet. I am not looking for re-pasting of that code. What I am looking for though is weather or not 3.3-3.5 released a new function that does something upon theme_init, I saw some sort of hook, but I can't remember where, in the codex, dealing with doing things after a theme has been initialized..

Any one know?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You might be looking for the `after_setup_theme` hook:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme

Comment: can I use this same function to do something after deactivation? The example seems to say so but im curious

Comment: you can play with  `$_GET['previewed']` and `$_GET['theme']`

Comment: -1 as this hook is fired at each WP init. It is fired after including the functions.php file of the theme, therefor it is not an "activation" hook.

Comment: yes true, but the fix for that is mentioned on the Codex page, to check for the above GET parameters or $_GET['activated']

Comment: This is a bad answer Ive posted here long time ago, please avoid it, one cant remove accepted ones, thx

Answer (score 45):

For anyone stumbling upon this question; there is an action you can hook into (added 3.3.0) which is fired only on activation of a new theme: `after_switch_theme`

```
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'mytheme_setup_options');

function mytheme_setup_options () {
  //doing a thing...
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_switch_theme

To do something on *deactivation* of a theme you can use the sister action: [switch_theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/switch_theme)

Answer (score 3):

With the theme preview features it is unlikely that there will ever be a theme activation hook since themes need to work even without being "activated".

Comment: Good point @mark-kaplun

Answer (score 2):

After trying @sleepingkiwi method i encountered a problem. A client might try a different theme (even if just for a moment), this might create a problem due to the fact that the "on theme activation" hook we created ran twice.

The best method is using after_switch_theme in concert with Wordpress "update_option" to save and later check an activation noticethus making this method bullet proof.

Example:

```
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'sgx_activation_hook');
function sgx_activation_hook() {
    if(get_option('SOMEPREFIX_theme_activated') != '1') {

        update_option( 'SOMEPREFIX_theme_activated', '1' );

        // RUN THEME_ACTIVATION STUFF HERE

    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, the codex specifies that it only triggers for the current theme: `Theme functions attached to this hook are only triggered in the theme (and/or child theme) being activated.` [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_switch_theme)

Comment: But that's good, isn't it? we also need to do some cleanup after theme is turned off - but in general, I would think that it is good since its a theme related thingy

Comment: Sure, it makes it easier

Answer (score 1):

I use this code to create the hooks `register_vuewp_theme` and `unregister_vuewp_theme`, so I can attach functions to these hooks easely.

```
function register_vuewp() {
    $one = get_option('vuewp_theme');
    if (false == $one) {
        update_option('vuewp_theme', 'on');
        do_action('register_vuewp_theme');
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'register_vuewp');

function unregister_vuewp() {
    delete_option('vuewp_theme');
    do_action('unregister_vuewp_theme');
}
add_action('switch_theme', 'unregister_vuewp');
```

Answer (score 0):

The action hook after_switch_theme sometimes may fail because it fires only if the old theme still exists. This is written in the [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_switch_theme/).

You can also check it directly in wp-includes/theme.php in the function check_theme_switched() where the action hook is added. You will see that the action hook "after_switch_theme" is inside the condition if ( $old_theme->exists() ) {....}

If you want to be sure the hook fires every time a theme is activated, and no matter if the old theme still exists, you can create your custom hook by hooking the change of the option "stylesheet".
Every time a theme is activated that option stores the name of the new active theme. So:

```
add_action( 'update_option_stylesheet','my_theme_activation_hook',20,3 );
add_action( 'update_site_option_stylesheet','my_theme_activation_hook',20,3 ); //For multisite installations

function my_theme_activation_hook( $old_value, $value, $option ){
    //It adds an action hook after theme activation, no matter if the old theme still exists
    do_action( 'my_after_theme_activation');
}
```

Then you can use your action hook "my_after_theme_activation" or whatever you want to call it.

This method is not perfect because a plugin could also update the option "stylesheet" without a real theme activation. I don't see why they should do it, but it's allowed, and you never know. So, I would take that into account.
Use it if for you it's not a problem that it fires also if a new theme is not really activated, but one of the plugins just changed the option "stylesheet".

You could also directly hook the change of the option "theme_switched" instead of "stylesheet". Not tested this,  but looking at the code it looks like it fires two times when you activate a new theme. The first time to save the old theme stylesheet, and a second time to save the value "false".